# Install CUDA 8 on linux mint 18.2

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, nvidia, cuda

I'm running Linux Mint 18.2 "Sonya" and want to install **CUDA 8**. When I install it using package manager it install Cuda 7.5 instead:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit
...
nvidia-cuda-dev is already the newest version (7.5.18-0ubuntu1).
nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (7.5.18-0ubuntu1).
```

I need to force to install version 8. How to do it?

Comment: This is more of a suggestion, I don't have access to a mint system. NVIDIA does not officially support Linux Mint. I am making the assumption that since mint is also a debian based. The installation method for ubuntu should work.Make sure you stop the xserver desktop environment through the pseudo terminal before installing through the run file.

Comment: Download the ubuntu run file from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and see this question on how to turn off the xserver desktop environment from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25668/how-to-close-x-server-to-avoid-errors-while-updating-nvidia-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the next steps

```
Installation Instructions:
1 `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb`
2 `sudo apt-get update`
3 `sudo apt-get install cuda`
```

Extracted from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads